# Function declaration in protocol with variable input argument list

Tags: swift

I have various fetcher classes in my application and I want to create a protocol named `Fetcher`.

All my fetcher classes have functions like 
`final func fetch(code: String) -> Void`, `final func fetch() -> Void`, `final func fetch(department: String, registrationYear: String) -> Void`

Hence, I tried to create this protocol as

```
protocol Fetcher {
    static func fetch(_)
}
```

however, it didn't accept that approach.

Do you have any suggestions?

As a sidenote; it doesn't always have to have inputs in type `String`, I need more generic solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How are you using `Fetcher`? The reason for such a protocol to exist would be to know that it responds to a particular function, but considering that all your fetcher classes take different parameters, they don't truly have anything in common. Swift doesn't allow you to define this protocol because it isn't actually promising anything. The solution is to not define a protocol for this at all.